# GAN loss function

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, gan

I am new to deep learning field and I want to synthesize as accurate as it can be, can someone tell me how to construct loss function for such model, any answer will be a great help please do not hesitate to answer.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Deep Learning (or even if you have some experience), I recommend to use one of the classic architectures.

[Here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html) you can find a simple tutorial of how to build a GAN in Pytorch.

[Here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.07875) you can find the paper of the WGAN, that is the one that works normally the best for me.

[Here](https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/gan-wasserstein-gan-wgan-gp-6a1a2aa1b490) a medium blog that can be useful since everything is explained.

And [here](https://github.com/eriklindernoren/PyTorch-GAN/blob/master/implementations/wgan/wgan.py) some code that can help you to see how actually loss functions are implemented.

```py
# Adversarial loss
## Generator
loss_G = -torch.mean(discriminator(gen_imgs))
## Discriminator
loss_D = -torch.mean(discriminator(real_imgs)) + torch.mean(discriminator(fake_imgs))
```